# Titanium - HTTPClient: open new controller onload

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, httpclient, onload

Hi i'm developing an android app test, which uses the HTTP protocol to communicate with a remote server and DB. It's a simple login page.

Now i've two controllers: `index.js` and `newuser.js`.

This is `index.xml`

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <TableView>
        <TableViewRow>
            <TextField id="user" borderStyle="Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED" color="#336699" top="10" left="10" width="250" height="60" />
        </TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow>
            <TextField id="password" borderStyle="Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED" color="#336699" top="10" left="10" width="250" height="60" />
        </TableViewRow>
        <TableViewRow>
            <Button id="loginBtn" onClick="doLogin" title="Login" />
        </TableViewRow>
    </TableView>

    <Menu id="menu" platform="android">

    <MenuItem id="addBook"
    title="Nuovo Utente"
    onClick="addNewuser"
    showAsAction="Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM" />
    </Menu>

    <View id="view_indicator">
        <ActivityIndicator id="ind" message="Loading..."/>
    </View>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

and this is `index.js`

```
loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

loginReq.onload = function() {
var json = this.responseText;
var response = JSON.parse(json);
if (response.logged == true) {
    alert("it's all ok");   

} else {
    alert(response.message);
}
$.view_indicator.hide();
}

function doLogin(e) {

if ($.user.value != '' && $.password.value != '') {
    loginReq.open("POST", "http://solimeo.sviluppofacile.it/login.php");
    var params = {
        username: $.user.value,
        password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest($.password.value)
    };
    $.view_indicator.show();
    loginReq.send(params);
} else {
    alert("Username/Pasword are required");
};
$.user.blur();
$.password.blur();
}

function addNewuser () {

var addnewuser = Alloy.createController("newuser").getView();
addnewuser.open();

}

$.index.open();
```

With this code, everything works good. My problem is when i try to open a new controller in `loginReq.onload`, in `index.js`.

I've created a new controller, `loggedin.js` to display the information about the user, and i try to open it. But there are many errors in the console. I thought that the problem could be the controller, but i've the same errors if i call `addNewuser()` function, that calls a good and tested controller

The errors are

```
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: (TiHttpClient-1) [13616,13616] HTTP Error (java.net.SocketException): recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1296)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:677)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:653)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1328)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

I've moved `$.view_indicator.hide();` into `if...else` block.

So the right code, for the `loginReq.onload` is

```
loginReq.onload = function() {
var json = this.responseText;
var response = JSON.parse(json);
if (response.logged == true) {
    var args = {

        name: response.name,
        email: response.email
    };
    var loggedUser = Alloy.createController("loggedin", args).getView();
    loggedUser.open();
    $.view_indicator.hide();

} else {
    alert(response.message);
    $.view_indicator.hide();
}

}
```